# 指定したアルバム内への画像の保存方法について

Tags: ios, swift

iOSにて、あるボタンを押して「写真」配下にアルバムを作成し、そのアルバム内に撮影した写真を保存する機能を加えようとしています。

ただ、アルバムの作成はできたものの、そのアルバムを指定して写真を保存するということができていません。(下記では、「カメラロール」に保存されてしまいます。)

こちらの方法について見つけることができず、ご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

なお、現在作成しているコードは下記のとおりです。

【アルバムを作成する】

```
@IBAction func tapAddBookBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var titleTextField: UITextField?

    //タイトル入力をpopupで求める
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "タイトル登録", message: "本のタイトルを入力してください", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //cancelボタン
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Pushed CANCEL")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //タイトル登録ボタン
    let registAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "登録", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        print("regist")
        print(titleTextField?.text)

        let albumName :String = readPhotoAlbum.applicationName + (titleTextField?.text)!

        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
            self.request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
            },completionHandler: { (isSuccess, error) -> Void in
                if isSuccess == true {
                    print("Success!")
                }
                else{
                    print("error occured")
                }      
        })    
    }
    alertController.addAction(registAction)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        titleTextField = textField
        textField.placeholder = "Title"
    }

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

【画像を保存する(カメラロール)】

```
@IBAction func tapSaveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    //保存確認
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "保存確認", message: "本当に保存してよいですか?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //保存確認->cancel
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Pushed CANCEL")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //保存確認->保存
    let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "保存", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        print("save")

        //savingView配下のeditingPhoto等を1枚の画像として保存
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.editingPhoto.frame.size, false, 0)
        self.savingView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let exportImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //写真保存(「特定のアルバム」内には保存できていない。)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(exportImage,
            self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

なお環境は、iOS9,xcode7.0.1です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

---

※追記
Harawoさんの回答を参考にし、下記で動くことを確認しました。

【アルバムを作成する】

```
@IBAction func tapAddBookBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var titleTextField: UITextField?

    //タイトル入力をpopupで求める
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "タイトル登録", message: "本のタイトルを入力してください", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //cancelボタン
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Pushed CANCEL")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //タイトル登録ボタン
    let registAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "登録", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        print("regist")
        print(titleTextField?.text)

        let albumName :String = readPhotoAlbum.applicationName + (titleTextField?.text)!

        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
            self.request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
            },completionHandler: { (isSuccess, error) -> Void in
                if isSuccess == true {
                    print("Success!")
                }
                else{
                    print("error occured")
                }      
        })    
    }
    alertController.addAction(registAction)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        titleTextField = textField
        textField.placeholder = "Title"
    }

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

【画像を保存する(カメラロール)】

```
@IBAction func tapSaveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    //保存確認
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "保存確認", message: "本当に保存してよいですか?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //保存確認->cancel
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Pushed CANCEL")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //保存確認->保存
    let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "保存", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        print("save")

        //savingView配下のeditingPhoto等を1枚の画像として保存
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.editingPhoto.frame.size, false, 0)
        self.savingView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let exportImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //アルバム名を指定する
        let albumTitle = titleTextField

        var theAlbum: PHAssetCollection?

        // アルバムを検索
        let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options: nil)
        result.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(object, index, stop) in
            if let theCollection = object as? PHAssetCollection where
                theCollection.localizedTitle == albumTitle
            {
                theAlbum = theCollection
            }
        })
        // アルバムにイメージを保存
        if let anAlbum = theAlbum {
            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(exportImage)
                let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: anAlbum)
                albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
                }, completionHandler: nil)
            print("save image into the Album.")
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 試していないので恐縮ですが、 [objective c - Save Photos to Custom Album in iPhones Photo Library - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954380/save-photos-to-custom-album-in-iphones-photo-library) ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます、サイト拝見し試してみます。経過についてまたお知らせさせて頂きます。

Comment: [Assets Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730)は、iOS 9よりDeprecatedになりました。代わりに、[Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)を使えと、Appleがインフォメーションを出しています。

Comment: @Harawo さん、ありがとうございます、無事動かすことができました。別途追記させていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8より、Photo.appのライブラリにアクセスするフレームワークに、**Photos Framework**が推奨されることになりました。

[Photos Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)

以下、一例として、「MyAlbum」という名前のアルバムに、`UIImage`インスタンスを保存するコードを載せておきます。（ボタンを押したら、保存）

```
@IBAction func savePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let albumTitle = "MyAlbum" // アルバム名
    let savingImage = UIImage(named: "a.png")! // 保存するイメージ
    var theAlbum: PHAssetCollection? // アルバムをオブジェクト化
    // フォトライブラリからMyAlbumを検索
    let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options: nil)
    result.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(object, index, stop) in
        if let theCollection = object as? PHAssetCollection where
        theCollection.localizedTitle == albumTitle
        {
            theAlbum = theCollection // 見つかったら、theAlbumに代入
        }
    })
    // アルバムにイメージを保存する
    if let anAlbum = theAlbum {
        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
            let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(savingImage)
            let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
            let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: anAlbum)
            albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
        }, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        print("MyAlbum was not found.")
    }
}
```

iOS 9より*Assets Library Framework*はDeprecatedになります。ご注意ください。Assets Libraryより、Photosのほうがいくぶん使いやすくなったかなという印象があります。